# Converting jQuery to react: I can't seem to make handle toggle and animate.css work in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a student trying to learn React and I am super lost on how to convert a set of codes from jQuery to react. This is what I have so far.

***Note***: I got the scrollHandler function working and need work on the ScrollUpButton function. Thank you.

Before:

```js
 // slide-up script
        $('.scroll-up-btn').click(function(){
            $('html').animate({scrollTop: 0});
            // removing smooth scroll on slide-up button click
            $('html').css("scrollBehavior", "auto");
        });

        $('.navbar .menu li a').click(function(){
            // applying again smooth scroll on menu items click
            $('html').css("scrollBehavior", "smooth");
        });

        // toggle menu/navbar script
        $('.menu-btn').click(function(){
            $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
            $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");
        });
```

After:

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// import Animate from 'animate.css-react';
import Navbar from '../Navigation/Navbar'
import "animate.css/animate.min.css";



export default function Scroll() {
    
   
    const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);
    
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
    
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {

        
        const navBar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
        const scrollUpBtn = document.querySelector(".scroll-up-btn");
        const Html = document.querySelector(".html");
        const ScrollLink = document.querySelector(".navbar .menu li a");
        const MenuButtonI = document.querySelector(".menu-btn i");
        const MenuButton = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
        const navBarMenu = document.querySelector(".navbar .menu");
        
        const scrollHandler = () =>  {
            if(window.scrollY > 20) {   
                navBar?.classList.add("sticky");
               
            }else{
               navBar?.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
            if(window.scrollY > 500) {
                scrollUpBtn?.classList.add("show");
            } else {
                scrollUpBtn?.classList.remove("show");
            }
        }
         
        const ScrollUpButton = () => {
            scrollUpBtn.onClick = () => {
                <ScrollAnimation animateIn="fadeIn" scrollTop= "0">
                    Html... this is the start of my confusion...
                </ScrollAnimation>
            }

            ScrollLink.onClick = () => {
                Html.css("scrollBehavior", "smooth") 
                //I am lost here too... 
            }
            MenuButton.onClick = () => {
                
                navBarMenu.handleToggle("active");
                MenuButtonI.handleToggle("active")
                //I don't think I am using handleToggle right...
            }
        }



        window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
        };

    }, []);
    return (
        <></>
    )
}
```

This may be a tough one. I thank you ahead for even looking at my code!

Comment: What you are needing is a bit of Javascript DOM Manipulation API. Try replacing "Html... this is the start of my confusion..." with [`Html.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). And [to add CSS to a DOM element](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp), use `Html.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth"` instead of `Html.css("scrollBehavior", "smooth")`

Comment: If you want to know how to toggle states on click with React hooks, you can check out [this article](https://dommagnifi.co/2020-12-03-toggle-state-with-react-hooks/) as a building block. Also, to use boolean states, just use `const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false)` (without the double quotes) instead of `"false"`